# What is the easiest way to work around SUMPRODUCT

Tags: excel, indexing, formula

What is the easiest way to work around `SUMPRODUCT` to return text/characters rather than numbers?

I am trying to build a database of jobs we are doing, and `SUMPRODUCT` has worked great with numbers, but now I wish to pull other information such as client name, project manager, etc.

The SUMPRODUCT formula I am using is:

`=SUMPRODUCT(--('2016'!B6:B371=$B1983),'2016'!L6:L371)`

Can I replace `SUMPRODUCT` with something to pull text/characters?

All help is much appreciated!  Thanks :-)

Comment: You want to return multiple cell values in one cell? or is it a one to one relationship?

Comment: either you need `Join` (VBA) or `INDEX` / `MATCH` or you need to explain how to sum up text...

Answer (score 1):

If you only need to return one cell where $B1983 equals the first value in the search range you can use INDEX/MATCH or VLOOKUP:

INDEX/MATCH:

```
=INDEX('2016'!L6:L371,MATCH($B1983,'2016'!B6:B371,0))
```

VLOOKUP:

```
VLOOKUP($B1983,'2016'!B6:L371,11,FALSE)
```

Comment: Thanks Scott!  Its actually several cells, but maybe I can use the index/match individually.  I appreciate your help :-)

Comment: @adminadvice if it is several cells then INDEX/MATCH is not the way to go.  It will return the first only.  Give some test data and expected outcome in your original post and we can help better.